# Xunit -Moq always returning a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am having an issue with my moq when I try to return data, of `serviceResponse` but it's not coming

I tried to write unit test in Xunit for service layer

My controller

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetHospitals(
    [FromQuery] HospitalRequestFilter hospitalRequestFilter, 
    [FromServices] IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions> options)
{
    var serviceResponse = await this._hospitalService.GetHospitalsAsync(hospitalRequestFilter, true);
    return OkResponse<HospitalQueryModel>(serviceResponse, true);
}
```

My controller's unit test

```
public async Task GetHospitals_WithOutFilter_ReturnsAllData()
{
    //Arrange
    MockServiceFactory mockServiceFactory = new MockServiceFactory();
    var hospitalServiceMock = mockServiceFactory.GetHospitals();

    var loggerMoq = new Mock<ILogger<HospitalsController>>();
    ILogger<HospitalsController> logger = loggerMoq.Object;

    ApiBehaviorOptions apiBeaviorOptions = new ApiBehaviorOptions() { };
    var mock = new Mock<IOptions<ApiBehaviorOptions>>();
    mock.Setup(ap => ap.Value).Returns(apiBeaviorOptions);

    var hospitalValidation = mockServiceFactory.GetHospitalValidation();
    HospitalsController HospitalController = new HospitalsController(logger,hospitalServiceMock,hospitalValidation);
    
    //Act
    var filter = new HospitalRequestFilter() { Code="Abc",Name="Abc hospital"};
    var hospital = await  HospitalController.GetHospitals(filter,mock.Object);
    
    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(hospital);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to be able to help you, please share with us the definition of `MockServiceFactory`.

Comment: I don't see any mocking done on the `hospitalServiceMock`, specifically on the `GetHospitalsAsync` method, is this mocked in the `MockServiceFactory`?